# Laptop will not boot

Tags: hard-drive, boot, performance, bios, operating-systems

This is a dell studio 1558 laptop. Now, something is wrong with the charger that it won't charge the laptop, but the laptop can turn on and operate properly as long as it is attached. It has been like this for a while, but it's not the problem. My problem is that as of yesterday, It takes several minutes to get past the "dell" startup logo (where is says "f2 setup" and "f12 boot options"). After it gets past, it beeps as normal to tell me about the charger and gives me the f2/f12 options and f1 to continue as normal. I can press f12 to get into boot options and load into my live USB BackTrack 5 ISO, but after "startx" it just stays at a black screen. I can also access BIOS setup, but see nothing that would help the problem. When I boot to the HDD, it gives me this

```
Intel UNDI, PXE-2.1 (build 083)

Realktek PCIe GBE Family Controller Series V.2.29 (06/30/09)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable
PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM
Operating System not found
```

Also, pressing f8 gives me the same results as booting as normal. It is running Windows 7 Ultimate, dual-core Intel i3 @ 2.27ghz and 4gb RAM. I think there is an issue with the HDD, as the "Operating System not found" would lead me to believe. Is this a fixable problem?

Comment: Is your HD detected by the BIOS ? Check the connection... try another live cd other than Backtrack (try partedmagic)

Comment: you can take that hd out and connect it to another computer to see if is fine

Comment: I'll try an ubuntu cd I have, and then maybe I'll test the hdd in another laptop

Comment: There should be hardware diagnostics, use F12, then select Diagnostics from the menu.

Answer (score 0):

There should be [on board hardware diagnostics](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/xlob/dtg/en/troubles.htm#wp1101057), use F12, then select Diagnostics from the menu, test the hard drive, post back any errors

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same problem. It means that there is something wrong with your hard disk. Your PC cannot boot from it and it so is trying to boot from LAN and it fails.

How to fix it:

- is your disk detected in BIOS (if not, check physical connection of your HDD)
- check boot order in BIOS (my HDD was missing in Boot submenu of PhoenixBIOS (Toshiba) - i had to hit number 1 key and it appeared again)
- boot with install/recovery CD, go to the recovery mode with command line and try to fix your disk with chkdsk, fixboot (bootrec /fixboot) and fixmbr (bootrec /fixmbr) utilities